# Neo4j How to access a property in a map with key containing dollar sign $

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc, dollar-sign

I have a json in the following format:

```
{"_id":"someid123"
"role": "Customer",
"itemDate": {
"$date": 1579687615849
  }
}
```

I want to access the itemDate.$date to add it as a property of my node
When I try:

```
call apoc.merge.node(["InteractionItem"], {id:item._id}, {date: item.itemDate.$date}) 
yield node as i_item return i_item
```

I get the following error:

```
Invalid input '$': expected an identifier
```

Please let me know if there is any solution for working with "$"  dollar signs or a solution to clean the dollar signs off of a map.

Thanks.

P.S: I'm working with Neo4j 4.4.3

Comment: You need to escape the name with ``: 
```item.itemDate.`$date` ``` should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this using 

```
`
```

 such as:

```
call apoc.merge.node(["InteractionItem"], {id:item._id}, {date: item.itemDate.`$date`}) 
yield node as i_item return i_item
```